# Prometheus don't see actuator endpoints in docker. Get "http://<container-name>:8080/actuator/prometheus": tcp ip:8080:connection refused

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, prometheus

I have a problem with my Prometheus container. Can't connect with `/actuator/prometheus` from other services. Then i get an error:

```
Get "http://notification-service:8080/actuator/prometheus": dial tcp 172.24.0.13:8080: connect: connection refused
```

or

```
server returned HTTP status 404
```

[ss from prometheus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyaSL.png)

I trying to send curl request (with container ip) and at start i really get 404 error, but after a few minutes i get normal response.

yml file with one example service

```
services:
  ticket-service:
    container_name: ticket-service
    image: <docker_hub_nick>/ticket-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-ticket:5431/ticket_service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-ticket
      - broker
      - zipkin
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    depends_on:
      - bet-service
      - ticket-service
      - chat-service
      - notification-service
      - wallet-service
```

ticket .properties

```
spring.application.name=ticket-service

management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

prometheus .yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     1m
  evaluation_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 1m
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'easywin-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'ticket_service'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['ticket-service:8080']
        labels:
          application: 'Ticket Service'
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to define the ports for your services?
As I recall, you need to define different listener ports for every service, hence a default of 8080 is not possible for all services in a docker-compose file.

Comment: I don't think so, coz all of containers have different ip in docker.

Comment: SOLUTION: I remove all of containers/images and now it's work. `docker system prune -a`